# Normal ES6 class in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it okay/bad practice for me to use a regular, plain 'ol javascript ES6 class in my React project, so that it does not extend component? I am wondering if this is bad to meddle with plain class instances using the `new` keyword. If so, what is the alternative if the class is purely functional with no UI?

Comment: You can use whatever JavaScript you like in React, it doesn't have to extend anything.

Comment: It depends on what you are planing to use the class for. Maybe you could give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's bad practice. In my projects I typically build a class for my API call methods to import into my components.